# How to run an Insert statement for each item in the SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a table variable as below:

```
declare @countries table (countryId int)
```

which has 5 records in it.

I'd need to write a separate insert statement for each countryId in the list, like:

```
insert into Countries (ID) VALUES (countryId)
```

How would that be possible without using a cursor?

Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `insert ... select` instead of `insert ... values`:

```
insert  Countries 
        (ID) 
select  countryId 
from    @countries
```

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into Countries (ID)
SELECT CountryId FROM @countries
```

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records

Answer (score 2):

You will use an `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM`

```
INSERT INTO Countries (ID)
SELECT countryID
FROM @countries
```